# MIFARE DESFire EV1 content removal

Tags: mifare, apdu, contactless-smartcard

Is there a way to reset a DESFire card to its original state? Any command to format and remove all content?

I've read that DeleteApplication apdu command removes the application and its files but the space remains unusable.

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the **FormatPICC** command.
It deletes all Applications and Files and frees the eeprom space.
Command byte is **0xFC**, you need prior PICC Masterkey Authentication always.
The usage of this command can be irreversibly disabled by the **SetConfiguration** command.

Comment: could you please explain : The usage of this command can be irreversibly disabled by the SetConfiguration command.

Comment: There is a command that disables Formatting for the remaining card life time. There is no way around, just test the FormatPICC command after Authentication. It will either work or throw an error(i never tried so i dont know which error will be thrown)

Comment: Can somebody please verify this statement from https://help.cardexchangesolutions.com/en/step_2_desfire_encoding.htm with regards to EEPROM space reclaim after `0xFC` format picc operation. The statement is:  **"Please, note that formatting the card does not recover the memory space used by the files and applications. Repeatedly formatting a card will end up in exhausting the available memory space."**  

Due to lots of testing, I've been formatting like crazy, and I want to know if this is zeroing out the eeprom free space as a result. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [taplinx](https://www.mifare.net/en/products/tools/taplinx/) you can easily format your card by this code

```
   desFireEV1.format();
```